# Solving a linear inequality without choosing points to check

Tags: inequality

Consider an inequality like this:

```
(2x-1)/(x+5) > 0
```

If we start by multiplying both sides by (x+5), we get 2x-1>0, which has the solution x > 1/2. However, the solution also includes x < -5. The only way I know how to do this is to find where the denominator equals zero (obtaining the point x=-5), and then choosing a point to the left and right of that point and determining if each of those points satisfies the inequality. This seems horribly non "algebraic" (for lack of a real term?) - that is, it seems like something they might teach you in high school, but there is really a more solid way to do it that just requires more advanced techniques. Is there a "better" way to do this type of problem?

Comment: multiply by $(x+5)^2$ instead.

Comment: And then what? That leaves (x+5)(2x-1) > 0 , now how do you find the solution x < -5 ?

Comment: look at the sign of the product in the segments separated by $-5$ and $1/2.$

Comment: A product of two real numbers is positive, iff both factors have the same sign. In your case, we must have either ($2x-1>0$ and $x+5>0$) or ($2x-1<0$ and $x+5<0$). The first case gives $x>1/2$ and $x>-5$ (which means $x>1/2$), and the second case gives $x<1/2$ and $x<-5$ (which means $x<-5$).

Comment: google sign chart, or sign chart method, and you will find plenty of links.

Comment: Mirko - that is exactly the kind of "beginners" method I was talking about - that is, I would never imagine a mathematician saying "next, I drew a big grid and calculated the sign for every combination". @sranthrop - I see, after doing the multiplication abel recommended, this is a nice explanation. So in general, we are trying to get the expression into a form where we can apply some kind of argument that we know the sign of (like a product of two real numbers)? If you post an answer with this description I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in a comment (but not necessary), multiply the whole inequality by $(x+5)^2$ and obtain $(2x-1)(x+5)>0$. On the left hand side we now have the product of two numbers which is positive if and only if both factors have the same sign. This gives us two cases: (1) $2x-1>0$ and $x+5>0$, (2) $2x-1<0$ and $x+5<0$. In case (1) we obtain $x>1/2$ and $x>-5$, which is equivalent to $x>1/2$. In case (2) we get $x<1/2$ and $x<-5$, which is equivalent to $x<-5$. So the answer is: $(2x-1)/(x+5)>0$ iff $x<-5$ or $x>1/2$.